# How does the ICC determine whether a country's internal probe on breaches of international laws are sufficient or not?

Tags: israel, international-criminal-court

> According to the ICC’s Rome Statute, it cannot intervene if a country
> properly self-investigates.
>
> **So the greatest battle over whether the ICC would get involved in the
> Israeli-Palestinian conflict has always been about whether it would
> recognize Israel's own internal probes as sufficient.**
>
> This has huge implications, because if IDF and government officials
> are indicted, over 125 ICC member state countries, including most of
> the EU, could be put in the difficult position of being obligated to
> arrest IDF and top Israeli government and military officials. Any such
> trend could even potentially impact the future willingness of Israelis
> to join IDF combat units and heavily impact Israel's national security
> strategy.

https://www.jpost.com/arab-israeli-conflict/gaza-news/article-771036

How does the ICC determine whether a country's internal probe on breaches of international laws are sufficient or not? I was reading this article and it seems to suggest that the ICC may not believe that Israel's internal probe on violation of international laws are sufficient, and thus possibly investigate Israel's actions in the near future. What does the process look like, how does it ensure transparency and objectivity?

Comment: There's quite a lot of information about [how the court operates](https://www.icc-cpi.int/about/how-the-court-works); it's up to the Office of the Prosecutor to judge if there is a case to be answered. But I'm not sure if you're asking about the investigative process (who does what, how a case is initiated, how they gather evidence, etc), or what the precise legal basis is for their decisions (legal definitions, what constitutes a sufficient internal investigation, etc). The latter may be more of a question for Law SE.